# How to find out why OllyDbg crashes?

Tags: ollydbg

I'm using OllyDbg v2.01 to analyse a specific binary. The binary is calling *createProcess()* and afterwards it's checking the return value via *test eax, eax*.
EAX contains 00000001 so the createProcess() call must have been successful. Nevertheless, OllyDbg crashes if I want to step over *test eax, eax* and I have absolutely no idea why. Is there any way to find out what's the problem for Olly? Normally, I can see if there is an access violation or something else going on which might bother Olly but in this case, there is nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can debug OllyDbg with another instance of OllyDbg:

- In OllyDbg process #1, run OllyDbg process #2.
- In OllyDbg process #2, run your target binary.
- When OllyDbg process #2 crashes, you can analyze the crash via
  OllyDbg process #1.